# undefined reference to `DES_set_odd_parity'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, openssl

gcc, Ubuntu.

Have done:

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Build with -lssl, but during linkage get error:

> undefined reference to `DES_set_odd_parity'

?

EDITED:
g++ linear_des.cpp -lssl

Comment: What is exact command used for compilation? Are your libraries being linked in the end?

Comment: can you post the full command used to do the compilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DES_set_odd_parity` is part of `libcrypto` so you should try linking that as well. Something on these lines:
`g++ linear_des.cpp -lssl -lcrypto`
Hope this helps!
PS: It might be a good idea to make use of `pkg-config` tool & compile something on these lines:
`g++ linear_des.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl)`